# Increase progress of ProgressBar in JavaFX via multiple threads

Tags: java, javafx, download, progress-bar

I'm creating a JavaFX application which would send multiple files over network, and I want to have a progress bar for the number of bytes sent. I already have the total size of the files which are about to be sent, however, I don't know how to increase the progress bar.

The problem is, I am sending the files concurrently, so I can't just set progress in my download class, as that would get overwritten by another threat.

This is what my download class look like:

```
        iStream = socket.getInputStream();
        bufferSize = socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];
        int count;
        while ((count = is.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
            bos.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
        bos.close();
        is.close();
```

And I'm executing the class the following way:

```
List<Callable<String>> downloadTasks = new ArrayList<>();
Callable<String> download = new Download(new File(path), portnumber);
downloadTasks.add(download);
es.invokeAll(downloadTasks);
```

I have the total number of bytes in variable `long totalSize` in both classes.

Can you please help me on how I would achieve the bytes progress bar? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only update the progress bar from a single thread: the FX Application Thread. So the threading issue is moot; you can just increment a property representing the total number of bytes downloaded, and arrange to only update it from that thread.

So something like:

```
public class UploadProgressMonitor {

    private final long totalBytes ;
    private long downloadedBytes ;
    private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper progress = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper() ;

    public UploadProgressMonitor(long totalBytes) {
         this.totalBytes = totalBytes ;
    }

    private void doIncrement(long bytes) {
        downloadedBytes += bytes ;
        progress.set(1.0 * downloadedBytes / totalBytes);
    }

    public void increment(long bytes) {
        if (Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) {
            doIncrement(bytes);
        } else {
            Platform.runLater(() -> doIncrement(bytes));
        }
    }

    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty progressProperty() {
        return progress.getReadOnlyProperty() ;
    }

    public final double getProgress() {
        return progressProperty().get();
    }
}
```

Now you can do things like:

```
long totalBytes = ... ;
UploadProgressMonitor monitor = new UploadProgressMonitor(totalBytes);
progressBar.progressProperty().bind(monitor.progressProperty());
```

and if you give each task a reference to the `UploadProgressMonitor` it just needs to do:

```
    int count;
    while ((count = is.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
        bos.write(bytes, 0, count);
        monitor.increment(count);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but the problem is, the progress bar stops at about 90%. If I calculate the size of int count after the download, it's about 90% of the total size in bytes reported by OS / Files.size(). Do you have any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: I think it has something to do with threads. If I send just 1 file, it's goes to 100%. If I send two equal files, it goes to about 50%.

Comment: @Peter No... to debug you can check the `count` for each download is equal to the expected total size for the individual file.  Make sure you are calculating the totals correctly and make sure every time you send the buffer you are incrementing the monitor (e.g. make sure you're not missing the last one, or some similar bug). This just sounds like there's a bug in your code. Again, the code I posted is basically all single-threaded.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. It works just fine. I made a pretty made mistake and create a new upload progress monitor for each thread....